# Generator function causing exceptions to be caught after all processes complete

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, multiprocessing, generator, python-itertools

I wrote this short POC to help understand the issue I am having with the hope that someone can explain to me what is going on and how I can fix it and/or make it more efficient.

My goal of using iterators, itertools and generators is because I didn't want to store a huge list in memory, as I scale up the list will become unmanageable and I didn't want to have to loop over the entire list to do something every single time. Note, I am fairly new to the idea of generators, iterators and multiprocessing and wrote this code today, so, if you can clearly tell I am miss understanding the workflow on how these things are suppose to work, please educate me and help make my code better.

You should be able to run the code as is and see the problem I am facing. I am *expecting* as soon as the exception is caught, it gets raised and the script dies, but what I see is happening, the exception get caught but the other processes continue.

If I comment out the `generateRange` generator and create a dummy list and pass it into `futures = (map(executor.submit, itertools.repeat(execute), mylist))`, the exception does get caught and exits the script as intended.

My guess is, the generator/iterator has to complete generating the range before the script can die, which, to my understanding was not suppose to be the case.

The reason I opted in using a generator function/iterators was because you can access them the objects only when they are needed.

Is there a way for me to stop the generator from continuing and let the exception be raised appropriately.

Here is my POC:

```
import concurrent.futures

PRIMES = [0]*80

import time

def is_prime(n):
    print("Enter")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("End")
    1/0

child = []
def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        for i in PRIMES:
            child.append(executor.submit(is_prime, i))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(child):
            if future.exception() is not None:
                print("Throw an exception")
                raise future.exception()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT: I updated the POC with something simpler.

Comment: Is the thing you want to parallelize mainly bound by CPU speed or by I/O? If it's the latter, multiprocessing is not a good idea.

Comment: Threading is hard to get right ;-(

Comment: If it is really prime detection, you will have to use multiprocessing. If it's I/O, I would recommend [`trio`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); it's one of the very few concurrency solutions that do exceptions right.

Comment: This is just a POC, not what I am actually doing @L3viathan

Comment: It's not really possible to cancel running processes like this. What you can do is iterate over `child` and `.cancel()` all containing futures, but a few processes will still execute regardless. Not the full 80 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to cancel running futures immediately, but this at least makes it so only a few processes are run after the exception is raised:

```
import concurrent.futures                                                  

PRIMES = [0]*80                                                            

import time                                                                

def is_prime(n):                                                           
    print("Enter")                                                         
    time.sleep(5)                                                          
    print("End")                                                           
    1/0                                                                    

child = []                                                                 
def main():                                                                
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        for i in PRIMES:                                                   
            child.append(executor.submit(is_prime, i))                     
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(child):              
            if future.exception() is not None:                             
                for fut in child:                                          
                    fut.cancel()                                           
                print("Throw an exception")                                
                raise future.exception()                                   

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                 
    main()
```

Comment: Comment was the key, even though I had it before, it seems to work here, nice touch, thank you.